# Boost Testing Framework return code

Tags: boost, boost-test

What is the meaning of return code of `unit_test_main` function from Boost Testing Framework ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can find [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-runners.html#utf.user-guide.runners-exit-status-summary), `unit_test_main` can return `boost::exit_success` if there were no errors or either `boost::exit_exception_failure` or `boost::exit_test_failure` depending on whether there were uncaught exceptions or not.

PS:
If you pass your test program the command line option `--result_code=no`, `unit_test_main` will always return `boost::exit_success`.

Comment: boost::exit_success is return code 0, boost::exit_exception_failure is return code 201, and boost::exit_test_failure is return code 201. On my platform, boost::exit_failure is 1.